# C: Add and remove elements in an array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have an array of structs, and each struct working as a list of elements.
I need to add multiple objects to each struct and my add function it's not working properly.

This is the Structure:

```
typedef struct object book, *list;
struct object{
int type;
int quantity;
list next;
};
```

This is how I'm defining my array and what I have in the main() function:

```
row_n=4 //fixed just for now
cols_n=3

product **t;

t= (product **)calloc(row_n, sizeof(product *));  // array of row pointers 
for (int i= 0; i<n; i++) {
t[i]= (product *)calloc(cols_n, sizeof(product));  // array of cols prod structs 
}

t[1][1].type= 5; //only for testing
t[1][1].quantity= 15; //only for testing
list_all(t,row_n,col_n); //list all elements inside each array, its working as intended
insert(t, 3, 6); //Trying to insert more books
insert(t, 6, 10);
insert(t, 9, 50);
```

This is the list_all function:

```
void list_all(product **t , int size_n , int size_m)
{
int i,j;
product *p;

for(i=0;i<size_n;i++){
    printf("--- row: ---: %d\n", i+1);
    for(j=0;j<size_m;j++){
        printf("--- col: ---: %d\n",j+1);
        p= &t[i][j];
        do {
            printf("Book Type:%d Amount:%d\n", p->type, p->quantity);
            p= p->next;
        } while (p!=NULL);
    }
  }
}
```

This is here my problem actually resides, I need to fix this insert function:

```
void insert(product **t, int id, int quantity)
{
product *p, *aux = NULL;
p=&t[0][0]; //doing it only in one position to test
if((aux = malloc(sizeof(product))) == NULL)
    printf("Memory error\n");
else
{
    aux->type=id;
    aux->quantity=quantity;
    p->next = p; }
p = aux;
}
```

I need a remove book function too but I want to fix this problem first.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What is happening? Did you use a debugger to understand ?

Comment: Right away I can tell you this: in your object struct, the field `next` should be of type `list*` (pointer to list).

Comment: the problem is, how to add multiple data to the lists inside each structure.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message?

In you code:

```
p->next = p;
```

seems should be:

```
aux->next = p;
```

In that way, you insert an product as a head of list.

Comment: I'm not getting any error message, but when I print all the array the book list inside [0][0] it's empty. I think the problem is that the 'p' pointer inside the function it's pointing elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues i see is

```
p->next = p; -> aux->next = p;
```

and

```
    //if
    p=&t[0][0];

    then 

    at the end 

    t[0][0] = p;
```

Because i think the t[0][0] still pointing to the earlier pointer rather than pointing to the start of the list so the add node is not visible